# How to enable perspective bar in eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I created eclipse 4 application project (RCP) with some sample content.

1. How to add perspective bar functionality to this application (exactly the same as in eclipse 4)?
2. Another question is -> how to add functionality which provides installation of plugins?

I spent too much time on looking for solution (of course I try to find some on vogela site etc.). It would be really nice if someone helped.

Comment: In a pure e4 application you will have to code the perspective bar implementation yourself. The existing code in Eclipse is part of the 3.x compatibility layer.

Comment: Ok, so is there any way to customize eclipse and create stripped down version of eclipse with chosen functionalities?

Comment: For eclipse provisioning you can have a look at the frameworks "p2" and more recently "Oomph"(https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring). P2 is basically the regular Eclipse Installation Manager with updatesite mechanisms. Oomph is handling updates AND configurations.

Comment: Oomph seems to be really nice tool for my needs. I spent some time today on customizing eclipse installation. In the end I realized that there is an option to create "self product" without jdt and any other functionalities but it didn't work. I made a lot of combination with creating this "self product" but It always throws some errors (for example: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found).

Is there any good tutorial about "how use oomph" to create "self product"?